# Putting two backgrounds one after the other in objective-c iphone game?

Tags: iphone, background, game-physics

Hi I am creating an iphone game

in my game layer, I have two identical background images but I want them to go one after the other.

Once the game animal (eg a penguin) crosses the first background, I want the first background to go after the second one-- becoming a continuous background until the game is over.

I have tried everything--- for loops, while loops and such but nothing seems to work

Does anyone have an idea for how I could go about doing this?

Thank you for any help you can provide me.

this is all I have so far after many different tries

```
- (id) init
{
    if((self = [super init]))
    {
        for ( int x = 0; x < 10000000; ++x)
        {
            CCSprite *bg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"level1.png"];
            [bg setPosition:ccp(160,240)];
            ccTexParams params = {GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_REPEAT, GL_REPEAT};
            [bg.texture setTexParameters:&params];
            [self addChild:bg z:0];

            CCSprite *bg2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"level1.png"];
            [bg2 setPosition:ccp(320,480)];
            ccTexParams param = {GL_LINEAR, GL_LINEAR, GL_REPEAT, GL_REPEAT};
            [bg2.texture setTexParameters:&param];
            [self addChild:bg z:0];
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the backgrounds are the identical you don't actually need 2 images, you can just set the texture rect position of the one and it will continuously move. If you call moveBackground on a timer or in the update method it will continually scroll.

```
-(void)init
{
    if((self=[super init]))
    {
        background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"background.png"]; 
        ccTexParams params = {GL_LINEAR,GL_LINEAR,GL_REPEAT,GL_REPEAT};
        [background.texture setTexParameters:&params];
        [self addChild:background z:0];
    }
}

-(void)moveBackground
{
    // Scroll background 5 pixels to the left
    int speed = 5;
    background.textureRect = CGRectMake(background.textureRect.origin.x-speed, 
                                        background.textureRect.origin.y, 
                                        background.textureRect.size.width, 
                                        background.textureRect.size.height);
}
```

Comment: No problem. If that solved your question you can kindly mark my answer as correct ;D

Comment: Feel free to take a look at my other questions that no one seems to have an answer to please!

Comment: You just have to click the little checkmark next to my answer. Here's the how-to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work Is the other question you are refering to "how to make my sprite jump"?

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at the other one today if no one beats me to it.