# Issues with background coordinate configuration in objective c with runAction?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

in my game i have two backgrounds going one after the other creating a continuous loop moving to the left. 
However, right now one goes, and the other does not follow it.

I have relentlessly tried different numbers but nothing seems to help.

Thank you for whatever help you can give to me.

```
if((self = [super init]))
    {

        self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

        background=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"testbackground88.png"];
        [self addChild:background z:1];
        background.position=ccp(500,240);
        id repeat1 =[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:
                                                             [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:7 position:ccp(-300,240)],
                                                             [CCPlace actionWithPosition:ccp(800,240)],nil]];
       [background runAction:repeat1];


        background2=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"testbackground92.png"];
        [self addChild:background2 z:1];
        background2.position=ccp(500,240);
        id repeat2 =[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:
                                                             [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:7 position:ccp(-300,240)],
                                                             [CCPlace actionWithPosition:ccp(800,240)],nil]];
       [background2 runAction:repeat2];
}
```

Comment: This is Cocos2D right? If so, you should tag it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if((self = [super init]))
{
    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

    //add an empty container sprite in 0,0 pos
    CCSprite container = [CCSprite node];
    [self addChild:container];

    // get the screen size and use it for positioning
    CGSize scrSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

    // add the sprites to the container
    background  =[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"testbackground88.png"];
    background2 =[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"testbackground92.png"];

    [container addChild:background z:1];
    [container addChild:background2 z:1];

    // use the background's widths to define it's in between distance. 
    int bgDist = ( background2.contentSize.width + background.contentSize.width) / 2;
    // the container's total travel;
    int containerTravel =  ( background.contentSize.width + background2.contentSize.width)/2 ;

    background.position     =ccp(scrSize.width/2, scrSize.height/2);
    background2.position    =ccp( (scrSize.width/2 + bgDist), scrSize.height/2);

    // move the container
    CCRepeatForever loopBgTravel =[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:
        [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:0 position:ccp(0,0)],
        [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:7 position:ccp(-containerTravel,0)]];

   [container runAction:loopBgTravel];
}
```

Feel free to ask again if this isn't working

Comment: Thank you so much. Quick question if you have time.

Comment: The container does not move at all?

Comment: It just shows background2 constantly. I tried playing around with it a lot. Don't know where to go from here.

Comment: I edited the code a bit, try again and tell me what happens. Unfortunately I don't have Xcode installed right now, so the code isn't tested

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your new question, and it's not a good idea to answer it here. You might want to start a new question about this

Answer (score 0):

the way you did that, you should always see bg2 over bg, as they move in the same exact position each time.
for example, if you want background2 placed on the right next to background 1, you can do something like

```
background2=[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"testbackground92.png"];
[self addChild:background2 z:1];
int bgWidth = background2.contentSize.width;
background2.position=ccp(500 + bgWidth ,240);
id repeat2 =[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCSequence actions:
    [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:7 position:ccp( (-300 + bgWidth) ,240)],
    [CCPlace actionWithPosition:ccp((800 + bgWidth ),240)],nil]];
```

It would be even better to add both sprites in a container Sprite, one next to each other, and perform the move actions on the container

Comment: Suraya, you asked a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906754/putting-two-backgrounds-one-after-the-other-in-objective-c-iphone-game) recently, and although you accepted the given answer, you seem to have problems implementing it. Judging from your other recent questions, I can see that you have a rather limited knowledge of cocos2d. No offense really, but my best advice for you is to take a complete tutorial course on cocos2d

Comment: I'm really sorry to see you got offended after all. When I started with cocos2d, I read http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/, which was really well organized, and I was able to follow with 0 experience on obj-c.

Comment: @JohnSmith - Don't take it personally, yannicuLar was genuinely trying to be helpful. If you have specific questions about cocos2d, we'd be glad to answer them, but it might not hurt to work through some introductory material if you are having problems with framework fundamentals. I think I saw that Ray Wenderlich had at least one set of good tutorials on this, and I've seen a few others out there.

Comment: Yeah sorry. That method by the way. It does put two backgrounds one after the other but does not create it in a way so it is a continuous background. (why I did not check it).

Comment: "John", did you reject my answer for that ? the positioning is a trivial matter (and your task to do), and I couldn't guess the numbers anyway since you didn't provide you sprite sizes. As you can see, I'm still trying to help you, but if you really appreciate the help, I hope you know what you're supposed to do